# Test for convergence: $\int_1^\infty \frac{\ln x}{x^2} \, dx$

Tags: integration

> Is this improper integral convergent or divergent?$$\int_1^\infty \frac{\ln x}{x^2} \, dx$$

I tried $\int_1^\infty \frac{\ln x}{x^2} \, dx \le \int_1^\infty \frac{\ln x}x \, dx$ but the RHS diverges, which makes this relation inconclusive. I think the integral diverges.

Comment: My first guess is that it converges because its dominant term is $1/x^2$. My second guess is that it converges because it drops asymptotically faster than the harmonic series $1/x$

Comment: hint: $\ln(x) \leq x^{a}$ for $a > 0$ for large $x$

Comment: @mm-aops I guess you meant for $a>1$?

Comment: nope, I meant $a>0$. it holds for $a > 1$ too, but it's useless in this case.

Answer (score 4):

It is $1$. Antiderivative is $-1/x-log(x)/x$.

Answer (score 2):

Using the L'Hôpital we find that

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\ln x}{\sqrt x}=0$$
so for $x$ sufficently large $$\frac{\ln x}{x^2}\le \frac1{x\sqrt x}$$
hence the given integral is convergent.

Answer (score 1):

use that $\int \frac{\log(x)}{x^2}dx=-\frac{1}{x}-\frac{\log(x)}{x}$

Answer (score 1):

First, we solve the integral using integration by parts (let me know if I should elaborate more on this)

$$\lim_{a\to\infty}\int_1^a \frac{\ln x}{x^2}\,dx=\lim_{a\to\infty}\left.\frac{-\ln x-1}{x}\right|_1^a=\Big(\lim_{a\to\infty}\frac{-\ln a-1}{a}\Big)+1$$

Now, we have to solve the limit

$$\Big(\lim_{a\to\infty}\frac{-\ln a-1}{a}\Big)+1$$

Apply L'Hôpitals Rule

$$=\lim_{a\to\infty}-\frac1a+1=1$$

Therefore, the integral converges to $1$.

Answer (score 0):

The integral converges: $\log x / \sqrt{x} \rightarrow 0$ as $x\rightarrow +\infty$, and
$$\int_1^{+\infty} \sqrt{x}/x^2 dx <+\infty.$$